# 2D countour in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How to make countour in gnuplot?
I want to plot:

```
5.300000e+04 1.300000e+02 5.436518e+06
5.300000e+04 1.325000e+02 5.126855e+06
5.300000e+04 1.350000e+02 4.803566e+06
5.300000e+04 1.375000e+02 4.457970e+06
5.300000e+04 1.400000e+02 4.103957e+06
5.300000e+04 1.425000e+02 3.734172e+06
5.300000e+04 1.450000e+02 3.352012e+06
.....
.....
```

I tried

```
cd 'G:\'
set view map
set dgrid3d
set ytics font "Times New Roman,12"
set xtics font "Times New Roman,12"
unset key
set palette rgbformulae 30,31,32
set decimalsign ','
set format y "%5.1f"
set format x "%5.1f"
splot "mapa.txt" using 1:2:3 with pm3d
```

with result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPana.png)

How to edit the right side to see the numbers completly and how is the scale called to change the font?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the width of the right margin with:

```
set rmargin at screen XXX
```

where XXX is a number from 0 to 1. Exactly the same for the top margin (tmargin), bottom margin (bmargin) and left margin (lmargin).

The color scale is called colorbox in gnuplot.

This more or less does what you want:

```
set view map
set dgrid3d
set ytics font "Times New Roman,12"
set xtics font "Times New Roman,12"
unset key

#Adjust the width of left and right margins so that the numbers fit
set lmargin at screen 0.1
set rmargin at screen 0.85

set palette rgbformulae 30,31,32
set decimalsign ','
set format y "%5.1f"
set format x "%5.1f"

# Change font of color scale
set cbtics font "Times New Roman,12"

splot "mapa.txt" using 1:2:3 with pm3d
```